# Why WPF application process occupy more memory?

Tags: c#, wpf

I  am developing an application using WPF. I am using a lot of Grid layouts. In my application, we use five services to communicate. All works fine. Sometimes, the application slowed way down so I checked task manager to see the memory usage. Then I saw 1.285 GB memory occupied by the application process.
I am using Windows 7 operating system. My Application developed in wpf 4.0 version. In that we use WCF , WIF etc for communication. I also used Images. Can any one give the solution why application process occupies more memory?

All the images are small images.Actually my application occupies nearly 110 MB.But sometimes it occupies 1.238 GB memory.I am not using Large images in my application.

Comment: Are you sure you are disposing everything when not needed anymore?

Comment: One of those images wouldn't happen to be 1GB in size, wouldn't it?

Comment: The question you want to ask is "how can I determine which parts of my application are requiring so much memory?"

Comment: What does the application do? Are you processing any large files or collections of data?

Comment: @Arafangion All the images are small.@Purplegoldfish I am not processing large files.@Davide Piras I disposing evertything that is not needed anymore.

Comment: You can try to use a tool like the free CLR Profiler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) or commercial one like RedGate's ANTS (read this article: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/tracing-memory-leaks-in-.net-applications-with-ants-profiler/) to identify the cause of the memory consumption

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic bullet answer here for you, it *really* depends on what you are doing in your application.

Its time to jump into the world of using a profiler and figuring out what is going on in your own app.